# How to access an item in a tuple when the tuple is inside a list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

My data looks like this:

```
>>> print nattach[:10]

[PPAttachment(sent=u'1', verb=u'is', noun1=u'chairman', prep=u'of', noun2=u'N.V.', attachment=u'N'), PPAttachment(sent=u'2', verb=u'named', noun1=u'director', prep=u'of', noun2=u'conglomerate', attachment=u'N'), PPAttachment(sent=u'3', verb=u'caused', noun1=u'percentage', prep=u'of', noun2=u'deaths', attachment=u'N')...]
```

I want a list of the third element of each tuple. How do I do this?

I tried to do a list comprehension (I think), but I got this error:

```
TypeError: 'PPAttachment' object does not support indexing
```

I hope you will help a newbie to Python.

Comment: where is the list comprehension you tried? And what is `PPAttachment` class?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `PPAttachment` is not a tuple, nor is it apparently a `namedtuple`. To get the third element, you'll probably want to access the value by name:

```
[attach.noun1 for attach in nattach]
```

Answer (score 0):

These are not tuples, but PPAttachment objects. I take it what you want is noun1, so maybe
something like

```
[pp_attachment.noun1 for pp_attachment in nattach[:10]]
```

will do the job